# vb.net: calling constructor when using generics

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

I have a number of different classes that implement interface IBar, and have constructors that take a couple of values.  Rather than create a bunch of almost identical method, is it possible to have a generic method that will create the appropriate constructor?

```
private function GetFoo(Of T)(byval p1, byval p2) as List(Of IBar)
  dim list as new List(Of IBar)

  dim foo as T

  ' a loop here for different values of x
     foo = new T(x,p1) 
     list.Add(foo)
  ' end of loop
  return list
end function
```

I get:

```
'New' cannot be used on a type parameter that does not have a 'New' constraint.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately not - .NET generics only allow you to constrain a generic type to have a parameterless constructor, which you can then call with `New T()`... you can't specify a particular set of parameters.

If you don't mind making your types mutable, you could create an interface which containing a *method* with the relevant parameters, make all your types implement the interface, and then constrain the type to implement that method and have a parameterless constructor, but it's not ideal.

Another option is to pass in an appropriate `Func` which takes `x` and `p1` and returns a new `T` each time. That would certainly be easy to use from C# - not *quite* so easy in VB IIRC, but worth considering nevertheless.

Comment: `Func` is OK nowadays in VB.net. It's still more verbose than in C# though.

Comment: @toddmo: It will work *if you constrain the generic type to have a parameterless constructor*. It won't work if you don't have that constraint.

Comment: @JonSkeet, If you had written `Sub Foo(Of T As {MyClass, New})` to show what you meant I would not have been confused. You said something but did not illustrate it. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the first option you mentioned: are you suggesting to create the object through a parameterless constructor, and then subsequently run a `function` which would do the job that was supposed to be done inside the original parameter-full constructor? In other words, something like `GetFoo(of T As IBar)(p1, p2): ... : Dim Bar as New T : Bar.FinishConstruction(x, p1)` (where `FinishConstruction` is part of `IBar`, which is implemented by `Bar`)?

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on Jon Skeet's answer, here's a possible solution using a `Func` parameter:

```
Private Function GetFoo(Of T As IBar)(ByVal p1 As Object, ByVal p2 As Object, ctor As Func(Of Integer, Object, T)) As List(Of IBar)
    Dim list As New List(Of IBar)
    Dim foo As T
    For x = 1 To 10
        foo = ctor(x, p1)
        list.Add(foo)
    Next
    Return list
End Function
```

usage would be similar to

```
    GetFoo(1, 2, Function(i, o) New BarImpl(i, o))
```

Comment: When I try to create Function BarImpl(i,o) as FOO { return new FOO(i,o) } then I get an error when calling GetFoo that says BarImpl is not defined.

Comment: `BarImpl` is a class implementing `IBar`, not a `Function`

Comment: This is a brilliant idea to use factory methods. It's probably preferable over constructors as well once it's in place, because you could do thinks like inject state into your construction method that you can't do in true constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to cal, a constructor even if it is not specified in generic constraints. See the example below.

```
    'This base class has no constructor except the default empty one
Public Class MyBaseClass

End Class

'this class inhetits MyBaseType, but it also implements a non empty constructor
Public Class MySpecializedClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass
    Public Sub New(argument As String)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Function CreateObject(Of ClassType As MyBaseClass)(argument As String) As ClassType
    'First, get the item type:
    Dim itemType As Type = GetType(ClassType)
    'Now we can use the desired constructor:
    Dim constructor As ConstructorInfo = itemType.GetConstructor(New Type() {GetType(String)})
    If constructor Is Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidConstraintException("Constructor ""New(String)"" not found.")
    Else
        Dim result As ClassType = constructor.Invoke(New Object() {argument})
        Return result
    End If
End Function

Public Sub RunTest()
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("+----------------------------------------------------+")
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to create a instance of MyBaseClass")
        Console.WriteLine("+----------------------------------------------------+")
        Dim myobject As MyBaseClass = CreateObject(Of MyBaseClass)("string value")
        Console.WriteLine(myobject)
        Console.WriteLine("Instance of MyBaseClass created")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("+----------------------------------------------------+")
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to create a instance of MySpecializedClass")
        Console.WriteLine("+----------------------------------------------------+")
        Dim myobject As MyBaseClass = CreateObject(Of MySpecializedClass)("string value")
        Console.WriteLine(myobject)
        Console.WriteLine("Instance of MySpecializedClass created")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting to use reflection. My constructor involves an interface; not sure how the `GetType(T).GetConstructor(New Type() { ITheInterface })` part is going to handle this, but I'm optimistic!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
Public CreateObject(Of T)() As T
    Dim newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), YourParameterHere)
    Return newObj
End Function
```

This will give you the new object. You can pass any parameters to this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the GetConstructor methode on the type of the generic.

```vb
GetType(T).GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {})
```